# Get <div> content with PHP

Tags: php, parsing, dom, preg-match, file-get-contents

I am trying to fetch the content inside a `<div>` via `file_get_contents`. What I want to do is to fetch the content from the div `resultStats` on google.com. My problem is (afaik) printing it.

A bit of code:

```
$data = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=cr&#q=" . $_GET['keyword'] . "&gws_rd=ssl");
preg_match("#<div id='resultStats'>(.*?)<\/div>#i", $data, $matches);
```

Simply using

```
print_r($matches);
```

only returns Array(), but I want to `preg_match` the number. Any help is appreciated!

Edit: thanks for showing me the right direction! I got rid of the `preg_` call and went for DOM instead. Although I am pretty new to PHP and this is giving me an headache; I found this code here on Stack Overflow and I am trying to edit it to get it to work. This far I only receive a blank page, and don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
$str = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&q=" . $_GET['keyword'] . "&gws_rd=ssl");
$DOM = new DOMDocument;   
@$dom->loadHTML($str);

//get
   $items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('resultStats');

//print
   for ($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++)
        echo $items->item($i)->nodeValue . "<br/>";

} else { exit("No keyword!") ;}
```

Comment: OMG. preg_match on HTML!!!! You are getting [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Comment: @jason-ooo Thanks for showing me the right direction! I got rid of the preg_ and went for DOM instead. 

Although; I am pretty new to PHP and this is giving me an headache... I found this code here on StackOverflow and I am trying to edit it to get it to work. This far i only receive a blank page, and dont know what I am doing wrong. Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/Y4GpT961

Comment: Please bear in mind that questions should be formatted to be useful to a long term readership - thus edit markers, and answers in questions, is not ideal. I'll try to fix it up.

Comment: I've moved your answer to a separate answer block. I converted your pasteboard to a code block - we don't like those too much as they can be brittle in practice. Thanks for posting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Posted on behalf of the OP.*

I decided to use the [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) and ended up something like this:

```
include_once('/simple_html_dom.php');
$setDomain = "https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&q=" . $_GET['keyword'] . "&gws_rd=ssl";
$str = file_get_html($setDomain);
$html = str_get_html($str);
$html->find('div div[id=resultStats]', 0)->innertext . '<br>';
```

Problem solved!